# Can't execute a script because module not found in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a lecture on Modules and Packages and I am trying to run a script that draws from code from another py file

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "D:/Python/Projects/myprogram.py", line 1, in <module>

     from mymodule import my_func

     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'
```

I clearly have a mymodule.py and myprogram.py inside my projects folder (D:\Python\Projects)

mymodule.py has

```
    def my_func():
       print("Hey I am in my mymodule.py")
```

myprogram.py has

```
 from mymodule.py import my_func

 my_func()
```

Can I get some help regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you're using Pycharm. Have you made sure to mark the source directory as the Sources root? In case you haven't, just go to the Project Files Menu on the left, and then:

> Right click the source folder->Mark directory as->Sources root->The
>   folder will turn blue.

You may have to restart Pycharm for the change to work. Make sure that the chosen folder is the right source, note that there's technically no problem if you mark more than one folder at the same time if you struggle to find the one causing the issue. Also note that Xilpex's answer is right, so in any case you shouldn't go back to your previous import.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Pycharm, and I've just now marked my Projects folder as a source folder but the error still persists.

Comment: Have you tried importing the module this way?

`import mymodule as mmod`

And then calling my_func() like this:

`mmod.my_func()`

Comment: I've just tried that way and it still doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: Well now that's really strange :( If both mymodule.py and myprogram.py are in the same folder this import method should work no matter the content of the imports, or so I thought... I hope you find whatever's causing this issue for you, I'll stay tuned since this will probably be something I could take into account myself someday, in case someone (or yourself) finds out the actual problem. I'm sorry I can't be of any more help.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you put in the time for help. I'll keep browsing for solutions.

Comment: So, I've somehow found a fix, When I was googling for solutions, some solutions referred to the Python Interpreters and other people's python interpreter were full of packages. My Python Interpreter had no packages, I was just playing around it and decided to switch my interpreters to Anaconda Python and now packages appeared and now I can run the script without any errors.

Comment: That's very good to know. I had a colleague experiencing a pretty similar issue before but it was related to Python's version, not the lack of package-compatibility itself. Anyways, I'm glad you could fix it. ^^

Answer (score 2):

That is because it isn't `from mymodule.py import my_func`, its `from mymodule import my_func`. In python, you don't import by filename, it's by the filename, without the extension.

Comment: Hi, even with ``` from mymodule import my_func ```, I still get the same error regardless.